# Getting error using JMeter behind a proxy

Tags: jmeter

I am new to JMeter and trying to run a test from behind a corporate proxy. I read on the same from apache site and followed the same process so as to run the test. However, i am still  unable to record a test from behind the proxy.

> This message always appears after pressing on 'Start' recording:

[image]

After that, I have changed apache port to 8000 as in below and made it different

> This time after pressing on start was this message

[image]

Comment: If you're talking about your computer's network connection requiring a proxy (when you are not even using JMeter that is), then see http://sqa.stackexchange.com/a/6492/11978

Comment: Change your port setting to 8070 or any other port

Answer (score 3):

You need to install CA certificate to the browser If you have installed JMeter then map for folder structure in windows, to find the root ca certificate, please follow the below steps & Choose the following options:-

> 1. Tools / Options
> 2. Advanced / Certificates
> 3. View Certificates
> 4. Authorities
> 5. Import certificate from path `...\JMeter\bin\ApacheJMeterTemporaryRootCA.crt`
> 6. Browse to the JMeter launch directory, and click on the file ApacheJMeterTemporaryRootCA.crt, press Open
> 7. Click View and check that the certificate details agree with the ones displayed by the JMeter Test Script Recorder
> 8. If OK, select "Trust this CA to identify web sites", and press OK
> 9. Close dialogues by pressing OK as necessary

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are on the right track, that last message should have generated certificate in BIN folder of your JMeter, i.e.

> your jmeter/bin

Certificate name will be: **ApacheJMeterTemporaryRootCA**

[image: Certificate]

You just need to import that certificate in browser in which you are going to record your script using JMeter.

Comment: actually I am not sure you got what I mean. As I know , jmeter should have same port as in browser setting. and This same port we use to connect to the internet without it we cannot run our application . I am confused with this . The first message appears if this was the case. The second message appears if I change port in jemter. at the end what shall I do to enable test recording?? –

Comment: Second message is perfect. it comes only if you have selected proper port which is not busy and available for jmeter. To enable test recording , as I mentioned , you need to import certificate in browser generated by jmeter as per second message. Also do not forget to set proxy in browser also.

Comment: he application I am going to test must have the correct http proxy and port defined in the browser in order to connect to the internet. How do you require to change it , it won't work if it is not 8080

Comment: Then you have to make port 8080 free first then only you will be able to use with jmeter. There is some another application is using port 8080 so jmeter is not able to use it.

Comment: Dear , I did what you mentioned, I used a diffident port and update the certificate with the browser but the message of certificate still appears. I made sure it was same configuration as in browser.

Comment: Certificate message will be there always when you click on **start** button. So do not worry about that message. just do recording. I hope that will work..

Comment: Actually it did not work , I started recording but nothing appears in the listeners.

Comment: Then there is something you are missing.. can you please add screenshot of your jmeter test plan?

Answer (score 1):

Take the following steps:

1. Change default JMeter HTTP(S) Test Script Recorded port to be different from default 8080. The easiest and quickest option is using "Recording" template (File -> Templates -> Recording). See [How to Save ‘Loads’ of Time Using JMeter's Template Feature](https://blazemeter.com/blog/how-save-%E2%80%98loads%E2%80%99-time-using-jmeters-template-feature) for instructions on using existing and creating new templates.
2. Configure your browser to use localhost as a proxy host and port 8888. Make sure that "no proxy for" input is blank or doesn't contain stuff like 127.0.0.1, localhost, ::1
3. If you're sitting behind the corporate proxy - you can "tell" JMeter to use your company proxy settings via the following command-line arguments:

   ```
   -H, --proxyHost <argument>
       Set a proxy server for JMeter to use
   -P, --proxyPort <argument>
       Set proxy server port for JMeter to use
   -N, --nonProxyHosts <argument>
       Set nonproxy host list (e.g. *.apache.org|localhost)
   -u, --username <argument>
       Set username for proxy server that JMeter is to use
   -a, --password <argument>
   ```

   See [full list of command-line options](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#options) to learn about other command-line arguments which you may find useful

Answer (score 0):

1. First add a Recording Controller in your Thread Group.
2. Next add a **HTTP(s) test script recorder** in the work bench.
3. Click on the **HTTP(s) test script recorder** .
4. In the Global Settings, change port from 8080 to any other number say - 7777.
   [image]
5. Go to Mozilla Firefox Options.
6. Go to Advanced settings.
7. Go to Network tab.
8. Go to Connection Settings.

[image]

9. Change to Manual proxy settings and change to port to 7777
10. Save the settings.

What was happening when you were trying to run the script earlier.
Actually the port on which you are trying to run the script on, is already in use by some other application and that is why you are getting the error.

Comment: the application I am going to test must have the correct http proxy and port  defined in the browser in order to connect to the internet. How do you require to change it , it won't work if it is not 8080

Comment: I guess you are recording using the Firefox browser. The thing is, port at both the side i.e. you script and the browser should be same and secondly that port should be free i.e. It should not be in use by some other application.

Comment: You only need to confirm that the port on which you are recording shud be set in chrome or firefox.
Also it should not be in use by any other application.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [Burp Suite](https://portswigger.net/burp/) application to set proxy.

Comment: Can you explain bit more in detail, how this will solve the OP issue of using JMeter.

Comment: Using this tool you can set proxy address, port, user name or password. After that you should set http address for jmeter, the machine which you install Burp suite.